# is it possible to preventDefault in html?

Tags: javascript, html

When i need to prevent default in react , i can put my handler function in onSubmit and everything works fine . `<form onSubmit={handler}>` . But how do i do the same in pure html ? I need acces to event object as well .

Comment: You can't handle events *at all* in "pure HTML", other than by allowing the browser to do what it normally does.

Comment: Yes , what i meant was using only html document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
<form id="form">
    Enter name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
    function onSubmit(event) {
        console.log(event);
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("The form was submitted");
    }

    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    form.onsubmit = onSubmit;
</script>
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit

Comment: Dude you are genius , now i now i can do this .

Comment: Thatk you :). Could you accept my answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

try do this :

```html
<form onSubmit="return false;">
```

Comment: Ok , but then how do i access event object ?

Answer (score -2):

You can do it with jquery library like this:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#your_form_selector', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("default submit action was prevented");
}
```

Comment: ?? This is certainly not "pure HTML", and the OP did not include the jQuery tag.

Comment: Yes, this is jquery.